# in my python 3 i cannot use urllib.request as it says i don't have this submodule so how can i access websites data?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web, urllib, python-webbrowser

I use python3 and urllib module has parse, error, robotparse only it does not commands like import urllib.request and urllib.request.urlopen so what the substitute or how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

go through the documentation and using it re-install the urllib and then try or you can try this script instead

```
 from urllib.request import urlopen
 html = urlopen("http://www.google.com/").read()
 print(html)
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, it's recommended to use the latest python http clients - urllib3 or requests

```
pip3 install urllib3

pip3 install requests
```

If you're trying to read a a website content using its URL you can do it with requests:

```
import requests

response = requests.get("https://stackoverflow.com/")
print(response.text)
```